# JDBC PreparedStatement - setTimestamp does not save the time

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am trying to save a `timestamp` to a `SQL` DB with the following line inside a `PreparedStatement`

```
ps.setTimestamp(5, new Timestamp(ITEM.getModifiedTime().getTime()));
```

---

When I debug and inspect the `PreparedStatement` I can see the date and the time with the `Java` and `SQL` types being `timestamp` but when I look at the DB the field appears like this

```
2016-08-08 00:00:00.000
```

How can I get the time to come through? I am using `SQL Server 2008`

Comment: How is that field declared in the database? Is it possibly defined as a DATE?

Comment: It is defined as `DATETIME`

Comment: Make sure On SQLServerDatabase side defined column is SMALLDATETIME

Comment: Can it not work with `DATETIME` ?